# PowerShell array containing integer '0' does not match "^(0|3010)$"

Tags: arrays, regex, powershell

I am trying to process return codes for multiple installers using a -match statement. I would expect the following code to return 'Installer(s) ran successfully' twice - but the -match statement does not work with an integer array containing the value 0...

```
$InstallerExitCodes = @()

$InstallerExitCodes += 0 # Pretend this is (Start-Process -PassThru -Wait installer.exe).ExitCode which returns 0 (success)

If ($InstallerExitCodes -match "^(0|3010)$") {
    Write-Output "Installer(s) ran successfully" # This does not run
}

$InstallerExitCodes += 3010 # Pretend this is (Start-Process -PassThru -Wait installer.exe).ExitCode which returns 3010 (success with reboot required)

If ($InstallerExitCodes -match "^(0|3010)$") {
    Write-Output "Installer(s) ran successfully" # This does
}
```

Comment: A regex can only be run against a *string*, not a number. `"$InstallerExitCodes" -match "^(0|3010)$"` will work, for example.

Comment: Change the `if` condition to `@($InstallerExitCodes -match "^(0|3010)$").Count -ge 1`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's not the issue here, PowerShell implicitly converts the LHS operand to string when using `-like` or `-match` operators

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen However, `$InstallerExitCodes -match "^(0|3010)$"` yields `0`, and `"$InstallerExitCodes" -match "^(0|3010)$"` yields `True`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew correct, this is expected behavior (see my answer for _why_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly matches `0` - the problem is not the regex comparison, it's the `if` statement.

PowerShell's scalar comparison operators have 2 *modes* of operation:

- Scalar mode: when the left-hand side operand is not enumerable, like `1 -eq 1`, PowerShell returns the boolean result of the comparison - that is, the expression evaluates to either `$true` or `$false`.
- Filter mode: when the left-hand side operator *is* enumerable, the comparison operator acts like a *filter*: `1,2,3 -gt 1` does not return `$true` or `$false`, it returns an array consisting of the items `2` and `3`, since they satisfied the constraint `-gt 1`.

Since `$InstallerExitCodes` is explicitly declared as an array, `-match` works in filter mode, and the result of the expression is no longer `$true` or `$false` (simplified):

```
PS C:\> @(0) -match '^0$'
0
```

The `if()` context makes PowerShell convert the expression result to `[bool]`, and since `0` is a *falsy* value, the `if` condition fails.

Either change the if condition to check for the *count* of the resulting filter mode expression:

```
if(@($InstallerExitCodes -match "^(0|3010)$").Count -ge 1){
  # success!
}
```

or use a containment operator to test:

```
if($InstallerExitCodes -contains 0 -or $InstallerExitCodes -contains 3010){
  # success!
}
```

or, you know, test the exit codes individually, instead of as a collection :-)

Comment: Thanks! It was the second part that I didn't understand - that integer '0' would get evaluated to 'false'.

Comment: What is actually happening is I need to uninstall all versions of a particular piece of software - I have a function call which does this and returns an indeterminate number of error codes (none, or sometimes one, or sometimes many). I then install the latest version if (and only if) all the old versions uninstalled successfully. Hence the need to check them in bulk.

Comment: Numeric types with value 0, empty strings, empty arrays, and 1-item arrays containing one of the aforementioned values (this is the case you ran into), all evaluate to `$false` when coerced to `[bool]` in PowerShell :-)

Comment: Just for my ref - and having done some more research into how null works on PowerShell - this also seems to work?
($null -ne ($InstallerExitCodes -match "^(0|3010)$"))

Comment: That would work as well in this scenario, yes - if `$InstallerExitCodes` contain no matching items, the expression resolves to `$null` :-)

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated.